# dotnet vstest with nunit not outputting write

Tags: .net-core, nunit

I am running nunit tests in a linux docker container using "dotnet vstest" and trying to write additional information and having huge issues.

I have tried using TextContext.Write, TextContext.Out.Writeline and Debug.Writeline. None of these will output the messages. The only thing have been able to do is write a different file and then have my script output that text file contents after running the tests.

Here is how I am calling the vs tests in my bash script

```sh
dotnet vstest tests/xxx.dll --logger:"console;verbosity=normal"
```